# How to style golf courses in Google Maps(sand dunes and green)?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am currently using the snazzy maps [Ultra Light theme](https://snazzymaps.com/style/151/ultra-light-with-labels) to style my Google Map.

The styling one would expect([landscape](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeStyleFeatureType)) to affect golf courses

`{
        "featureType": "landscape",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#f5f5f5"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 20
            }
        ]
    },
{
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#f5f5f5"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 21
            }
        ]
    }`

only partially styles it. One quirk, with regards to golf courses, the "green" and sand dunes will not be affected by the landscape styling. I am trying to figure out if there is indeed a styling setting that will affect golf courses in totality.

One can find the map it's in raw form [here](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Stanford+University+Golf+Course/@37.4225095,-122.1887787,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x808fa4d80a383d27:0x91e6414570c43c57!8m2!3d37.4225095!4d-122.18659), as well as the [styled version](http://jsfiddle.net/Unh2M/943/) for a side by side comparison. Thank you, and help is more than appreciated as always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into it for a bit, I found that there is no way to target golf courses intuitively. I tried, administrative, landscape, poi, road, transit, water, and they all did nothing. Google maps in their documentation does mention,

`"Stylers applied to a parent feature type automatically apply to all child feature types. Note however that parent features may include some additional features that are not included in one of their child feature types."`

I tried applying the style to all, i.e.: 
`{
        "featureType": "all",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#dedede"
            },
            {
                "lightness": 20
            }
        ]
    },`

and it actually affected golf courses. By putting all as the first style, and the remainder of the styles after it, "all" acts as a reset of sorts. This is the only current way I have found to specifically target golf courses.

Updated jsfiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Unh2M/946/)