# Google Maps API: What feature type is this?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In the image below you can see my styled version and the default version of a map. The beige coloured feature has popped up sometime during the last week and seems to mark some type of commercial area.

None of the feature types listed [in the API reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeStyleFeatureType) seem to affect it.

[image: Styled and unstyled version of a map highlighting the unknown feature]

These are the styles I have assigned to my version of the map.

```
googleMapStyle = [
      {
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "stylers": [
          { "visibility": "off" }
        ]
      },{
        "featureType": "road",
        "stylers": [
          { "visibility": "simple" },
          { "color": "#393939" }
        ]
      },{
        "elementType": "labels",
        "stylers": [
          { "visibility": "off" }
        ]
      },{
        "featureType": "water",
        "stylers": [
          { "color": "#303030" }
        ]
      },{
        "featureType": "landscape",
        "stylers": [
          { "color": "#2a2a2a" }
        ]
      },{
        "featureType": "poi",
        "stylers": [
          { "color": "#393939" },
          { "visibility": "off" }
        ]
      },{
        "featureType": "transit",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
          { "visibility": "off" }
        ]
      },{
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
        "stylers": [
          { "visibility": "on" },
          { "color": "#393939" }
        ]
      }
    ];
```

Does anyone know what feature type this is and how to get rid of it?

Comment: related question: [How to style golf courses in Google Maps(sand dunes and green)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38513342/how-to-style-golf-courses-in-google-mapssand-dunes-and-green)

Comment: @geocodezip thanks that question solved my issue as well.

Answer (score -1):

There seem to be undocumented feature types. In your case I found out that using featureType `building` affected those, ahem, buildings.

```
googleMapStyle = [
      {
        "featureType": "building",
        "stylers": [
          { "visibility": "off" }
        ]
      },{
      ...
      }
    ];
```

Comment: "building" doesn't seem to be a "featureType". Looks like whenever maps encounters an unknown "featureType" it is treated as "all" and because you had it as the first rule it worked and when I added as the last rule my whole map disappeared.